# How to stop having to npm start after a while, or everytime I make a change on the file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, npm, npm-start

I just started taking an coursera course on React. Everytime I make a change in the file, I get this message on Firefox:

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:3000.

So, if I `sudo npm start`I can access the url again. Also, if too much time passes, I have to sudo npm start again.

Is it how it's supposed to be or is there a way to make it automatic?

Comment: about:config in firefox and than network.dns.disableIPv6 what value you have set  true or false? the same network.dns.disablePrefetch ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using create-react-app, there is a watch mode in webpack which builds the react app if you change any files but create-react-app doesn't provide this function so there is a script in given gist to provide that functionality

https://gist.github.com/int128/e0cdec598c5b3db728ff35758abdbafd